# ASP.NET shows a tag not found error in a string

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I am using a `<connectionstrings>` tag in the web.config file in my ASP.NET code. In one of the connections I have to pass the UserID and password to access the database. the password is of the format `"test<X"`. but Visual Studio gives an error on this stating to close the 'X' tag. Please help!

Comment: Can you paste your connectionstring here, only keys, no values?

Comment: "Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=CAT;User ID=UID;Password=test<X" providerName="Client"

Comment: Hey i got it ... it is accepting if i use &lt; instead of '<' sign. Thanks :)